# Is it possible to embed a QWidget inside of a custom QGraphicsWidget?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qgraphicsscene, qgraphicswidget

I would like to embed a QWidget such as a push button or progress bar in my QGraphicswidget, but I have only seen examples of adding a QWidget to a QGraphicsScene i.e.

```
m_scene->addWidget(new QPushButton("Test Test"));
```

In my custom graphics widget I am drawing text and other custom shapes in the paint function.  I would think you would need to add the QWidget here, but I'm probably wrong.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Here is my overloaded paint function:

```
void TestWidget::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem 
    *option, QWidget *widget /*= 0*/)
{
    Q_UNUSED(widget);
    Q_UNUSED(option);

    QRectF frame(QPointF(0,0), geometry().size());
    QGradientStops stops;   

    //Draw border
    painter->drawRoundedRect(boundingRect(), 5.0, 5.0);
    //Name of the test
    painter->drawText(40, 20, m_name);

    //Status of test
    QFont font = painter->font() ;
    font.setPointSize(14);
    painter->setFont(font);
    painter->drawText(600, 20, m_status);

    //Arrow button
    QPolygonF poly;
    poly << QPointF(5, 10) << QPointF(25, 10) << QPointF(15, 20 )<< 
    QPointF(5,10);
    painter->setBrush(Qt::black);
    painter->drawPolygon(poly, Qt::OddEvenFill);   
}
```

Comment: use `QGraphicsProxyWidget`.

Comment: The examples you are referencing show how to add a QWidget to a QGraphicsScene.  They do not show how to embed a QWidget inside a QGraphicsWidget.

Comment: you have to use: `QGraphicsProxyWidget`, `QGraphicsProxyWidget *proxy = new QGraphicsProxyWidget` `proxy->setWidget(pointer_of_your_widget);` `m_scene->addItem(proxy)`. see http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-graphicsview-basicgraphicslayouts-example.html

Comment: @scopchanov I have added a custom QGraphicsWidget to a scene, and within that QGraphicsWidget I would like to add a QProgressBar.

Comment: @scopchanov I need to draw a large number of 2d items thus regular QWidgets will not work.  It will hopefully only be a rare case (one or two times) that I will need to draw a QWidget within my QGraphicsWidget.  Since I'm using QGraphicWidgets I need a QGraphicScene to draw them correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution

In order to embed a widget, e.g. *QPushButton*, in your subclass of *QGraphicsWidget* use [QGraphicsProxyWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsproxywidget.html) like this:

```
#include "TestWidget.h"
#include <QGraphicsProxyWidget>
#include <QPushButton>

TestWidget::TestWidget(QGraphicsItem *parent) :
    QGraphicsWidget(parent)
{
    ...
    auto *proxy = new QGraphicsProxyWidget(this);
    
    proxy->setWidget(new QPushButton(tr("CLick me")));
    proxy->moveBy(20, 40);
    ...
}
```

---

## Background

If you use `m_scene->addWidget(new QPushButton("Test Test"));`, which is [essentially the same](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html#addWidget) as:

```
QGraphicsProxyWidget *proxy = new QGraphicsProxyWidget();

proxy->setWidget(new QPushButton("Test Test"));
m_scene->addItem(proxy);
```

you add the *QPushButton* (through the proxy) **directly to the scene**.

If you want to make the *QPushButton* a **part of your custom *QGraphicsWidget***, set the parent of the *QGraphicsProxyWidget* to the instance of the custom *QGraphicsWidget*.

**Note:** There is no need to call *QGraphicsScene::addItem*, as (because of the parent/child relationship) the proxy will be added to the scene together with your custom *QGraphicsWidget*.

---

## Result

Using your `paint` method the result is similar to this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!  I'm glad that you added the moveBy function to show how to position the widget.

Comment: @MichaelJapzon, you are very welcome! If you have other questions, I would be glad to help if I could.

Comment: @MichaelJapzon, I suggest you to post a new one.